# PHP Contact Form Redirect Error

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have recently moved servers, and since i did my php contact form has gone a bit skew-wiff.

It works fine as a contact form, but the re-direct function ceases to exist.

I get this Error on the re-direct page:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/content/73/11511973/html/contact.php:14) in
>   /home/content/73/11511973/html/contact.php on line 20

Here is my contact.php code:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Order/Enquiry';
    $to = 'crookedcartoon@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = "From: ".$_POST['name'];

    $body = "From: $name\nE-Mail: $email\n\nMessage:\n\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p><center><br><img src="images/cat.jpg"><br><br><br><font size="4" face="Tw Cen MT">Your message has been sent! You will now be redirected to the home page.<br><br>Thank you for your message!</font></center></p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p><center><br><img src="images/cat.jpg"><br><br><br><font size="4" face="Tw Cen MT">Something went wrong, go back and try again! You will now be redirected to the home page.</font></center></p</p>'; 
    }
}

header('Refresh: 3; url=index.html')

?>
```

And here is my website with the page in full action:

[www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/contact.html](http://www.crookedcartoon.co.uk/contact.html)

Thank you,
-Alex

Comment: Use `header("Location: index.html");` instead of `header('Refresh: 3; url=index.html')`. Plus you do not have a closing `;` at the end of your `header('Refresh: 3; url=index.html')`.

Comment: Plus, the reason you are getting that error message (*"Cannot modify header information"*), may be caused by either whitespace above PHP, HTML, or the infamous `BOM` byte order mark. One of those reasons will cause that.

Answer (score 0):

You must not output anything before `header()`.

Remove all output before the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use header function only before ANY output is written. Basically at the beggining of script

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        header();
    } else { 
        echo '<p><center><br><img src="images/cat.jpg"><br><br><br><font size="4" face="Tw Cen MT">Something went wrong, go back and try again! You will now be redirected to the home page.</font></center></p</p>'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you're using `echo()` before you use `header()`. When you output content to the page you're effectively closing your HTTP headers. When you try to use the `header()` function again, because the headers have to be sent prior to any content, you're receiving that message as an error.

You can use a `meta-refresh` in the page's HTML header, if you want them to actually see the contents of the page for a couple of seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=/index.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is precisely accurate.  In an HTTP request/response, headers are the first items sent back to the user.  When you output text using `echo`, you're basically telling PHP "Okay, I'm done with the headers, and I'm ready to start outputting the body of my response."

I'd generally not recommend displaying a message to a user only to automatically redirect him a few seconds later because showing the intermediate page is an unnecessary step in the whole process.  Instead, I'd probably display the "success" message on index.html itself.  If you really want to do what you're going after, you can:

1. Grab your output using output buffering, and after you've issued your redirect header, flush the output buffer like so.  Do this by calling `ob_start();` before you `echo` anything, and then call `ob_end_flush();` after `header("...");`, or...
2. Display `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=index.html">` in the HTML of the page itself, or...
3. Don't automatically issue the redirect header, but instead provide a link to index.html on the "success" page